# how to blur the website when on a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, html, css

Im struggling to make this work with the code I have. Below is the code I currently have. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(function() {
  $('.uk-navbar-dropdown').on('mouseover', function() {
    $('.body').show();
  });
  $('.uk-navbar-dropdown').on('mouseout', function() {
    $('.body').hide();
  });
});
```

css code:

```
.body{
  position: absolute;
  display:none;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #000000;
  opacity: .5;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: body is class or tag?

Comment: class. I thought if it was the "body" class then it would take everything under the dropdown menu. Ive tried other classes as well, but if I'm doing it wrong then could you advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The index value for .body has to be higher than the content div, and it has to be on the same level as the content div.

```
<body>
<div class="body"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
</body>
```

Also, width and height for .body have to be 100%.

In your CSS there is no blur but opacity, it's not the same. In your case, it's going to be gray faded.

Try backdrop for blur:

```
.body {
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
}
```